# Alerting on a failed cron job

Tags: bash, shell, cron, centos

Is there anyway to alert on a cron job that may have failed to execute for whatever reason on a CentOS 7 EC2 instance? I'm looking for a tool or to review a process that anyone else might be using for something like this.

Comment: Can you post your crontab entry? By default an email would be generated if cronjob returns a non-zero result.  And what do you mean by an alert?  What kind of alert do you want to get?

Comment: No example yet but something like "5 4 * * * touch /home/user/cronTest " by alert, I mean something like an email e.g. if this task didn't run I would get notified in some capacity. You mentioned that email is an option, if you can add that as an answer I will accept it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good answer to your question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314640/how-to-make-cron-send-email-with-error-log-when-script-throws-errors

In summary it says:

```
20 6-10 * * 1-5 ~/job_failure_test.sh > ~/job_fail.log 2>&1 || mail -s "Errors" myemail@something.com < ~/job_fail.log
```

But follow the link to the question as there is some good pointers there.

Answer (score 2):

To get an email every time a cron job, you have scheduled to run, fails:

1. Redirect all of your standard output to `/dev/null` or to some file.
2. Use the `MAILTO` environment variable with a list (comma separated) of all the email addresses you want to receive the email notifications.

To avoid using the same value of MAILTO for every task you run, you can just write it in the crontab e.g.:

```
MAILTO="foo@bar.com"
0 5 * * * /bin/some_script > /dev/null
```

`MAILTO="foo@bar.com"` to the top of a `crontab` will cause any output from the cron job to be emailed. So we redirect the `STDOUT` to `null` and if any `STDERR` messages are present, they will get emailed to you.

---

[SRC](https://coderwall.com/p/nwqhxa/get-email-when-a-cron-job-fails)